# Clustering similar words with a pretrained word2vec and K means

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, word2vec

I am quite new at programming and word2vec models and I would really appreciate your help.

I have performed a BoW analysis on my data and have obtained the top 100 most predictive words. Now, I want to run those words through a pretrained word2vec model and organize them into different clusters using K means. The main goal is to establish the most predictive clusters. However, when I do the clustering, something goes wrong as my model gives me clusters containing single letters (though my 100 words are actual words and my data does not have single letters).

Below is a snippet of the code I am using (note that I have used a tutorial that has similar steps as these):

```
text = np.take(vectorizer2.get_feature_names(), pos_class_prob_sorted[:100]) #these are the extracted 100 predictive words from the BoW analysis

text = str(text)
tokenized_docs = word_tokenize(text)

tokenized_docs = list(tokenized_docs)


list_of_docs = text


#Trying to make clusters

def vectorize(list_of_docs, model=wv):
   """Generate vectors for list of documents using a Word Embedding

   Args:
       list_of_docs: List of documents
       model: Gensim's Word Embedding

   Returns:
       List of document vectors
   """
   features = []

   for tokens in list_of_docs:
       zero_vector = np.zeros(model.vector_size)
       vectors = []
       for token in tokens:
           if token in wv:
               try:
                   vectors.append(wv[token])
               except KeyError:
                   continue
       if vectors:
           vectors = np.asarray(vectors)
           avg_vec = vectors.mean(axis=0)
           features.append(avg_vec)
       else:
           features.append(zero_vector)
   return features


vectorized_docs = vectorize(tokenized_docs,model=wv)
len(vectorized_docs), len(vectorized_docs[0])

def mbkmeans_clusters(
    X,
    k,
    mb,
    print_silhouette_values,
):
    """Generate clusters and print Silhouette metrics using MBKmeans

    Args:
        X: Matrix of features.
        k: Number of clusters.
        mb: Size of mini-batches.
        print_silhouette_values: Print silhouette values per cluster.

    Returns:
        Trained clustering model and labels based on X.
    """
    km = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k, batch_size=mb).fit(X)
    print(f"For n_clusters = {k}")
    print(f"Silhouette coefficient: {silhouette_score(X, km.labels_):0.2f}")
    print(f"Inertia:{km.inertia_}")

    if print_silhouette_values:
        sample_silhouette_values = silhouette_samples(X, km.labels_)
        print(f"Silhouette values:")
        silhouette_values = []
        for i in range(k):
            cluster_silhouette_values = sample_silhouette_values[km.labels_ == i]
            silhouette_values.append(
                (
                    i,
                    cluster_silhouette_values.shape[0],
                    cluster_silhouette_values.mean(),
                    cluster_silhouette_values.min(),
                    cluster_silhouette_values.max(),
                )
            )
        silhouette_values = sorted(
            silhouette_values, key=lambda tup: tup[2], reverse=True
        )
        for s in silhouette_values:
            print(
                f"    Cluster {s[0]}: Size:{s[1]} | Avg:{s[2]:.2f} | Min:{s[3]:.2f} | Max: {s[4]:.2f}"
            )
    return km, km.labels_


clustering, cluster_labels = mbkmeans_clusters(
    X=vectorized_docs,
    k=10,
    mb=500,
    print_silhouette_values=True,
)
df_clusters = pd.DataFrame({
    "tokens": [" ".join(text) for text in tokenized_docs],
    "cluster": cluster_labels
})

print("Most representative terms per cluster (based on centroids):")


for i in range(10):
    tokens_per_cluster = ""
    most_representative = wv.most_similar(positive=[clustering.cluster_centers_[i]], topn=5)
    for t in most_representative:
        tokens_per_cluster += f"{t[0]} "
    print(f"Cluster {i}: {tokens_per_cluster}")
```

Can you please help me determine where am I going wrong with this code? For me, it seems that the model does not actually take those top 100 words into account and it seems like they are not going through the word2vec model.

Comment: That's a big chunk of code to try to understand & scan for errors (and yet not standalone complete). And without seeing exact problem output, it's less clear exactly where things may have gone wrong. But if you're expecting *word* outputs, but instead have *single-letter* outputs, that suggests that something that was expecting a *list-of-words* instead got a plain *string* instead - which Python will happily treat as a *list-of-single-character-words*. This might be happening in your code, or in the prior-trained word2vec training. (Are you sure that `wv` model is good? Where's it from?)

Comment: @gojomo, thank you for answering! I had imported the wv as wv = api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-300'). In my understanding, this is a pretrained word2vec model on Wikipedia. I have also made a variable list_of_docs, which consist of the top 100 predictive words from my previously done BoW analysis. I had also converted the words into strings, so that I would be able to tokenize them. Do you think that the fact that I had made them into strings could present a problem?

Comment: That code should result in a load of that GLoVe-trained set of word-vectors, yes. (Though: I would always recommend downloading the word-vector files yourself, from known sources, so you know where the files land & can examine them, then load them with specific other explicit methods.)

Comment: One possible source of the error, as described, remains some point in your code where a list-of-words was expected and a string (list-of-characters) used instead. But again, it's a lot of code to theorize about, and your question text doesn't actually show the disappointing output, or any interim bits of output to check interim steps, so it's hard to speculate on where the error is.

Comment: Hey! So do you have some success in Semantic clustering of words with word2vec?